# Запуск нескольких ботов на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли запустить 10 телеграм ботов используя Laravel ?

Comment: Сколько угодно можно запустить их, хоть на laravel, хоть на yii2 и пр.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать ? что запустить на ларавель проекте к примеру 10 ботов и чтоб они работали незавсисимо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускать можно как угодно и во сколько угодно потоков, от фреймворка это не сильно зависит. Как вариант, в Laravel можно создать 2 скрипта: первый получает события по телеграм боту и бросает их в очередь, а второй разгребает очередь используя Supervisor - он то и позволит запустить скрипт обработки в 10 и более потоках.
Подробнее: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration